# Reading specific data from a line in a text file to respective arrays, in Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, file, file-handling

[image]

This is in a text file

After each comma on the line, it’s a different piece of data, e.g.

the first data is first name, then surname, then contact number, then address, then college, then college id, then course, then specialization

I need to write a java program that will read the text file and for each line, and for each piece of data, will store the information into respective arrays in the program, for example, all the “first names” read will be stored in an array called “first name” and so on.

This was easy to for me to write in python using `line.split(“,”)` but java is totally different for me to understand

Comment: You should do some reading up on File IO in Java. First, you'll need to read in the file using a class such as BufferedReader or FileReader. These classes will allow you to read in the file, one line at a time. And then, on each line, the line.split(",") will work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can also achieve this in java using split method  by splitting the each line by separate in your case it is comma and you will get string array .Then iterate over the array and map your keys.

Consider below example

`String line = "Amit, 29";
 String []values = line.split(",");
 String name = values[0];
 String age = values[1];`

Comment: Might want to trim() those values to get rid of spaces